# vba excel userform preview print

Tags: excel, vba, printing, userform

Is it possible to preview print a user from in vba excel or print the user form to a place in a worksheet?

I already know this 
`UserForm1.PrintForm`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer.

It is not possible to display a Print Preview of a userform using only VBA.

It is possible to do so using a series of Wind32 APIs, as the userform is a Window. However, this is not trivial and requires a lot of code.